# My lightning web component successfully loads data only under Sys Admin and not as any other user

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC that loads in data by calling an Apex class with a SOQL query. It works when I am testing to view logged is as a system administrator, but when I try to view it logged in as another user, the data doesn't load in.

```js
@wire(getData, { accountId: '$recordId'}) 
    wireHandler({data,error}) {
        if(data) {
            //code
        } 
    }
```

When I view the console the `error` prints, but I don't know how to approach fixing this because all it gives me is taking me to an error..

Comment: What is the code for `getLoanApplications()`? Do your Apex logs show an exception being thrown?

Comment: What's the Org-Wide Default for `Loan_Application__c` and the sharing mode of the controller class? Or, another way, does the user actually have record-level access to this object?

Comment: Does the other user's profile have access to the apex class? You say the error prints, but what does it show if instead of `console.log('error');`, you add in the actual error returned `console.log('error ' + error);`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the details mentioned by David and Kris.

Comment: In the UI, go to Setup --> apex classes --> find your apex class and you should see `Security` button next to it. Click it and see if the user's profile is on the enabled side. In terms of the console, try `console.log('error ' + error.body.message);`.

Comment: That fixed it!! The user profiles were not on the enabled side. This fixed everything. Thank you so much!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Winter '21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm&release=228&type=5), users need access to the apex class of @AuraEnabled apex methods based on their profile.

For future reference, if you appropriately handle/display the error message returned from the wire - it would have told you the issue.

Instead of simply doing

`console.log('error')`

which only tells you that it went into the error path, you can actually display the message returned which, in this case, would've been along the lines of

> You do not have access to the Apex class named xxxxx.

`console.log(error.body.message);`

There's also this [reduceErrors](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils/ldsUtils.js) method showcased in the lwc-recipes that is useful for reuse to handle scenarios with more than one error.